# How could I insert/remove an edge in LLVM?

Tags: llvm, llvm-3.0, llvm-c++-api

Could I insert a new edge by changing its destination, and remove another edge by its source and destination. In other words, could I replace the basic block destination of an edge by another one, to make some modification in the CFG?

I tried `getEdge()` function in `ProfileInfo`, but it didn't work:

```
// to replace the basic block
Bb->getTerminator()->replaceUsesOfWith((*SI), (*rit));

// trying to set the new basic block as a new destination
xx = ProfileInfo::getEdge(Bb,(*rit));
```

Answer (score 1):

A basic block has a single terminator instruction. However, this terminator can be [one of several instructions](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#terminator-instructions) which are quite different. Some can have multiple edges. So it's not quite as simple as it seems you assume.

What you *can* do is look at the terminator of a block and modify the instruction to branch to a different destination. This depends on the instruction, and (of course) on your specific needs.

Comment: So, according to each type of terminator instruction there is a function to add new basic block to change the edge. How could I detect the type of terminatorInst and set the new basic block in an LLVM pass

Comment: @R.Omar: `BasicBlock::getTerminator` gives you the terminator instruction, and it can be tested to see its subtype with the usual LLVM RTTI techniques. See diagram here for available subclasses of `TerminatorInst`: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1TerminatorInst.html